# Use of optional argument stretch in \parbox

Tags: spacing, boxes, optional-arguments

I'm having some difficulty on how to use the "stretch" optional argument of \parbox. Is it supposed to equally interspace lines of text inside a box of determined size?

If I code it like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Text
  \fbox{\parbox[c][15cm][s]{5cm}{I want to stretch this text inside this box}}
\end{document}
```

This is the outcome I get:
[image: Example1]

I also experimented with \parbox and got some unexpected outcomes. In the following code, I merely deleted the alignment optional argument (default is center) from the previous test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Text
\fbox{\parbox[15cm][s]{5cm}{I want to stretch this text inside this box}}
\end{document}
```

As a result, this came out:
[image: Example2]

Which confused me, because I thought deleting the first optional argument would simply put it in default. I also didn't get why the text from the mandatory argument was substituted by the letter "s", a shortcut for "stretch" in the third optional argument.

Another test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Text
\fbox{\parbox[15cm]{5cm}{I want to stretch this text inside this box}}
\end{document}
```

Which yielded me:
[image: Example3]

In this last one, I deleted the stretch optional argument, but the height of the box was not drawn.

Why did I get those results? I'm barely a starter at TeX, so might me missing obvious points on the use of optional arguments.

Comment: I forgot to add “Welcome to TeX.SX!” when answering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With

```
\parbox[c][3cm][s]{5cm}{I want to stretch this text inside this box}
```

there is no stretchable glue in the box and indeed you get the warning

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected
```

If you want that the first line is at the top and the second line at the bottom, you need to make the interline glue stretchable:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\parbox[c][3cm][s]{5cm}{
  \setlength{\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip plus 1fil}
  I want to stretch this text inside this box
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to specify the second (and third) optional argument, you *must* specify the first. So

```
\parbox[3cm]{5cm}{...}
```

gives the same result as `\parbox{5cm}{...}`; unfortunately LaTeX doesn't do a check for the contents of the first optional argument, which should only be `c` (default), `t` or `b`. If it's different from any of these, it's silently ignored.

If you don't specify the third optional argument, it defaults to be the same as the first.

Comment: But in my second example, `\fbox{\parbox[15cm][s]{5cm}{I want to stretch this text inside this box}}` should then yield the same outcome as `\parbox{5cm}{...}` because I did not specify the first optional argument. However, what I got was the substitution of the text from the mandatory argument for `s`.

Comment: @PPA With `\parbox[15cm][s]{5cm}{I want...}` you get an error message; then the output is whatever LaTeX has been able to recover, probably different from what you had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of questions there;-)

> Is it supposed to equally interspace lines of text inside a box of determined size?

No, it simply doesn't add any glue itself so it relies on any strech glue within the content to fill the required space,

> Which confused me, because I thought deleting the first optional argument

You didn't delete the first optional argument, you changed its value from `c` to `15cm`.

Comment: Since the questions were all related, I thought separating them in different posts would be redundant. 
I'm completely unfamiliar with the term **glue** in TeX, but it makes sense. I'll look into it.

Comment: @PPA the LaTeX book calls stretchable space a "rubber length" but the TeXbook calls it glue (and TeX's logging output and primitive commands call it skip) but most people call it glue

Comment: @David what's the default value of the optional agument <height> in \parbox when this arg is not given?

Comment: @lyl please do not ask questions as comments on old answers. not using the option is not equivalent to using any value with the option, it takes a different code path. just as  in te horizontal case `\makebox{zzz}` is not equivalent to `\makebox[...]{zzz}` for any value of ...